# Using Spring Data style HAL in Spring Data Controller

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

In order to save a Spring Data Rest object with a foreign key to another object I can use a following JSON

```
{
     "studentName":"newObj",
     "department":"departments/2"
}
```

where department is a HAL link.

I wish to do some processing before the student is saved, without changing the default Spring Data Rest API.

How can I define a Spring controller endpoint so that it parses the resource link automatically and initializes the student object with the according department object?

Answer (score 1):

Either write an `ApplicationListener`

```java
public class BeforeSaveEventListener extends AbstractRepositoryEventListener {

  @Override
  public void onBeforeSave(Object entity) {
    ... logic to handle inspecting the entity before the Repository saves it
  }

  @Override
  public void onAfterDelete(Object entity) {
    ... send a message that this entity has been deleted
  }
}
```

or write an Annotated Handler

```java
@RepositoryEventHandler 
public class PersonEventHandler {

  @HandleBeforeSave
  public void handlePersonSave(Person p) {
    // … you can now deal with Person in a type-safe way
  }

  @HandleBeforeSave
  public void handleProfileSave(Profile p) {
    // … you can now deal with Profile in a type-safe way
  }
}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#events

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of this option, but it seems to be a bit constrained. I would like to have access to the request context and to be able to return a custom response, and put the logic in the controller.